# Dynamic class load in Java - refer classes

Tags: java, eclipse

I am just testing dynamic class load and am doing this:

```
package P1;
public class Class1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         Bird myBird = null;
         String myClassName = "P2.Bird";
         Class x = Class.forName(myClassName);
         myBird = (Bird)x.newInstance();
    }
}
```

`Bird` is a class from `package P2`, and `Class1` is from `P1`. What should I add in the code to make this work, as the `String myClassName...` line shows an error (class not found). I tried the same code after moving `Bird` in `package P1`, even then it doesn't work.

Related question: Why would someone use dynamic class load, does it have any advantages? It's much simpler(at least for me at first glance) to just use the "new" operator for static class loading, and in that case I know how to refer the class from a different package. Many thanks!

Comment: Related question: what if you don't know the name of the class at compile time?

Comment: A lot of dynamic class loading is done because you want to be able to configure your application and not have to hard code it into the code.

Comment: Thank you Dave and Sotirios, very helpful.

Comment: are you referring to some compile time error or runtime ? I cannot see any issue with your code, I hope the Bird class is compiled and that the class file is present.

Comment: Anugoonj: the Bird class is underlined as not recognised (ClassNotFoundException), I think the class is not referenced well or completely (it's located in a different package). However, even when I place Bird and Class1 in the same package, Bird is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the answer to your first question try mentioning full Package name. I have tried it and it works

Comment: Thank you vamslip! A question: don't I already do that via "P2.Bird"? Not sure what you refer to. (P2 is the package where the class Bird is located)

Comment: Yes you are right I have tried out the same code as you did and it works fine also Capital casing of package name is not desirable. Do you want to look at the code?

Comment: Thank you vamslip so much! I finally made it work too but only after I surrounded this statement `myx = (Bird)Class.forName("P2.Bird").newInstance();` (equivalent with lines 7-9 from my initial question) with a *throw-catch* (for a ClassNotFoundException). Does the same happen to you? Even though the class is found, if I don't add the throw-catch, the program doesn't run. Isn't it a bit weird? Does it have to do with how my Eclipse is configured?

Comment: You are right Sam you need to add a throw-catch to make it work, or else the exception would be unhanded if the class is not found! Hey by the way its vamsilp!!

Answer (score 1):

Your Bird class provides a default public constructor with no arguments?

Dynamic class loading can be useful for example to specify the class you want to use in a configuration file (you will come across that if you ever use log4j, or other libraries that allow the use of your own implementation to one of their interfaces). In that case, the library does not know about which class you will use, and you don't have to write code to initialise the library (which would be the alternative to dynamic class loading, but which is less convenient)